# Getting NPE in apache SOLR 8.11.2 while doing atomic update using add-distinct from my java based appication

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

`org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient$RouteException: Error from server at {hostname}/solr/collection_shard6_replica_t2737: java.lang.NullPointerException     at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AtomicUpdateDocumentMerger.doAddDistinct(AtomicUpdateDocumentMerger.java:466)   at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AtomicUpdateDocumentMerger.mergeDocHavingSameId(AtomicUpdateDocumentMerger.java:174)    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AtomicUpdateDocumentMerger.mergeChildDocRecursive(AtomicUpdateDocumentMerger.java:115)  at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AtomicUpdateDocumentMerger.merge(AtomicUpdateDocumentMerger.java:106)   at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.getUpdatedDocument(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:730)  at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doVersionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:380)    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.lambda$versionAdd$0(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:343)     at org.apache.solr.update.VersionBucket.runWithLock(VersionBucket.java:50)  at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:343)  at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:229)  at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedZkUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedZkUpdateProcessor.java:245)  at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader$1.update(JavabinLoader.java:110)    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$StreamingCodec.readOuterMostDocIterator(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:344)   at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$StreamingCodec.readIterator(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:292)   at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readObject(JavaBinCodec.java:338)   at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:283)  at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$StreamingCodec.readNamedList(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:245)  at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readObject(JavaBinCodec.java:303)   at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:283)  at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinCodec.java:196)    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:131)     at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.parseAndLoadDocs(JavabinLoader.java:122)    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.load(JavabinLoader.java:70)     at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:97)    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:82)     at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:216)    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2637)    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:791)  at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:564)     at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:427)     at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:357)     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:600)  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434)   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:177)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)  at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:322)     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:763)   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:400)   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:645)  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:392)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)      at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.getRouteException(CloudSolrClient.java:125)    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.getRouteException(CloudSolrClient.java:46)     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseCloudSolrClient.directUpdate(BaseCloudSolrClient.java:579)     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseCloudSolrClient.sendRequest(BaseCloudSolrClient.java:1076)     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseCloudSolrClient.requestWithRetryOnStaleState(BaseCloudSolrClient.java:934)     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseCloudSolrClient.request(BaseCloudSolrClient.java:866)  at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:214)   at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:106)     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:71)  at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:85)  at com.gdn.x.search.service.impl.SolrDataServiceV2Impl.redirectUpdateRequest(SolrDataServiceV2Impl.java:708)    at com.gdn.x.search.service.impl.SolrDataServiceV2Impl.updateAndHandleException(SolrDataServiceV2Impl.java:806)     at com.gdn.x.search.service.impl.SolrDataServiceV2Impl.updateThrottler(SolrDataServiceV2Impl.java:757)  at com.gdn.x.search.service.impl.SolrDataServiceV2Impl.update(SolrDataServiceV2Impl.java:880)   at com.gdn.x.search.service.impl.SolrDataServiceV2Impl.lambda$atomicUpdateList$61(SolrDataServiceV2Impl.java:2031)  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)   at com.gdn.x.search.other.service.helper.wrapper.ContextAwarePoolExecutor.lambda$wrap$0(ContextAwarePoolExecutor.java:35)   at datadog.trace.bootstrap.instrumentation.java.concurrent.Wrapper.run(Wrapper.java:46)     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at {hostname}/solr/collection_shard6_replica_t2737: java.lang.NullPointerException    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AtomicUpdateDocumentMerger.doAddDistinct(AtomicUpdateDocumentMerger.java:466)   at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AtomicUpdateDocumentMerger.mergeDocHavingSameId(AtomicUpdateDocumentMerger.java:174)    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AtomicUpdateDocumentMerger.mergeChildDocRecursive(AtomicUpdateDocumentMerger.java:115)  at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AtomicUpdateDocumentMerger.merge(AtomicUpdateDocumentMerger.java:106)   at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.getUpdatedDocument(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:730)  at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doVersionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:380)    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.lambda$versionAdd$0(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:343)     at org.apache.solr.update.VersionBucket.runWithLock(VersionBucket.java:50)  at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:343)  at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:229)  at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedZkUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedZkUpdateProcessor.java:245)  at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader$1.update(JavabinLoader.java:110)    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$StreamingCodec.readOuterMostDocIterator(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:344)   at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$StreamingCodec.readIterator(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:292)   at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readObject(JavaBinCodec.java:338)   at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:283)  at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$StreamingCodec.readNamedList(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:245)  at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readObject(JavaBinCodec.java:303)   at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:283)  at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinCodec.java:196)    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:131)     at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.parseAndLoadDocs(JavabinLoader.java:122)    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.load(JavabinLoader.java:70)     at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:97)    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:82)     at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:216)    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2637)    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:791)  at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:564)     at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:427)     at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:357)     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:600)  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434)   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:177)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)  at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:322)     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:763)   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:400)   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:645)  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:392)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)      at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:681)  at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:266)    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:248)    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.LBSolrClient.doRequest(LBSolrClient.java:369)  at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.LBSolrClient.request(LBSolrClient.java:297)    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseCloudSolrClient.lambda$directUpdate$0(BaseCloudSolrClient.java:555)    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)   at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:218)  ... 4 common frames omitted`

This issue is happening in my production environment when my java application was trying to update it with document `[SolrInputDocument(fields: [id=10001, promotionType={add-distinct=WHOLESALE}, lastUpdatedTime={set=1711433462524}])]`, where i am using solr 8.11.2 in production environment, i am not able to reproduce this in my local, in my local its working as expected
Can someone help here what can be the possible reason for this NPE?

Definition of this field "promotionType" in my managed-schema
{
"name":"promotionType",
"type":"string",
"docValues":true,
"multiValued":true,
"indexed":false,
"stored":true
}

Also, the document was present with id : 10001

i tried replicating in my local with same SOLR version 8.11.2, but was getting updating properly, in few instances it was failing in production

Environment difference between local and production,

in production, we have millions of data and its multi sharded whereas, my local has limited data and single sharded application